# tensor's value is danamically changing

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I found that the tensor's value is always changing in a loop. I list part of my code here:

```
agent_prob = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, 1], dtype = tf.float32)
feed_data = tf.ones([BATCH_SIZE, 1], dtype = tf.int32)

for time in range(STEP):
    agent_logits = agent(feed_data)
    agent_log_prob = K.log(K.softmax(agent_logits))[:, -1, :]
    index = tf.stack([tf.range(indices.shape[0])[:, None], indices], axis = 2)
    agent_loss = tf.gather_nd(agent_log_prob, index)
    agent_prob = tf.concat([agent_prob, agent_loss], axis=1)
```

I print out the `agent_prob.eval()` inside the loop and here are the first three loops results. You can see the values from the last iteration were replaced by other random values in the next one.

```
[[ 0.       -4.481065]
 [ 0.       -4.481065]]

[[ 0.       -4.481062 -4.479786]
   [ 0.       -4.481065 -4.479623]]

[[ 0.        -4.2824945 -4.4838    -4.4854503]
 [ 0.        -4.481065  -4.47854   -4.4854517]]
```

Anyone can explain it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to replace agent_prob with agent_loss? Or what is it?

Comment: "agent_loss" is the probability that I extracted from the logits with size [batch_size, 1]. In each iteration, I append the new agent_loss to the end of agent_prob along axis =1. For example, say agent_prob was initialized as [[0],[0]], (batch_size = 2). Then the first iteration agent_loss may be [[0.5],[0.6]], then the agent_prob will be updated as [[0, 0.5],[0, 0.6]], and the third iteration may be [[0, 0.5, 0.4],[0, 0.6, 0.3]] and so on. So the agent_prob is growing along axis =1 until the last time step and the value should't be changing. sorry for making the names kinda confusing!